# create and manage json object in localstorage

Tags: json, local-storage

I'm creating a media player for a website and I want to use localsotrage for storing and retrieving playlists, so the users can name their playlists and add their song to it and only the id of the song is going to be saved in the json object so the size of the localstorage would be very small.

first of all I want to make a localstorage with the key of playlist:

```
{
    "playlist": []
}
```

then as the users starts to create their own playlist it will be add to that json and would be something like this:

```
{
    "playlist": [
        {
            "lovesongs": ["1","15","7"],
        }
    ]
}
```

and then another day the user would create another playlist:

```
{
    "playlist": [
        {
            "lovesongs": ["1","15","7"],
            "sadsongs": ["4","17","25"]
        }
    ]
}
```

how can I do that? create, add and edit the playlist inside the json file located in the localstorage.

please do not refer me to another blogs or answers.

Thanks.

Comment: *"please do not refer me to another blogs or answers"* Like in "I am too lazy to read and you need to implement my requirements and then give me the code so that I can copy and paste it"? Certainly not.

Comment: You need to use `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`. What problems are you facing with that?

Comment: @Tomalak, the only reason that I asked that, is because I wanted to create the same structure that I couldn't accomplish by myself, I searched all the stackoverflow and forums.asp.net but they did not answer my question, pay attention to the whole question and requirements, if you think that a blog or example can help me please redirect me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JSON.stringify(), JSON.parse(), localStorage.setItem(), localStorage.getItem()